# VScode + Xdebug + Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Xdebug упорно игнорирует точки останова ((( Перепробовал уже кучу вариантов и никак не заставлю его работать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, в чем ошибка?

[image: Структура проекта]

docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/webserver
    container_name: '7.1.x-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini 
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2    
#    environment:
#      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9090 remote_enable=1 default_enable=1 remote_autostart=1
    
  mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: '5.7-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: tiger
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'sc-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
  redis:
    container_name: 'sc-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Dockerfile php-сервиса:

```
FROM php:7.1.32-apache

RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install tools & libraries
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils nano wget dialog \
    build-essential git curl libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev zip

# Install important libraries
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils build-essential git curl libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev zip \
    libmcrypt-dev libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 mariadb-client zlib1g-dev \
    libicu-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# PHP Extensions
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.8 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install curl \
    && docker-php-ext-install tokenizer \
    && docker-php-ext-install json \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini;

# install imagick
RUN apt-get -y install libmagickwand-dev
RUN pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 300M
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
max_execution_time = 200

zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/usr/local/etc/php/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/usr/local/etc/php/xdebug.log
```

launch.json:

```
{        
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug on Docker App",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
            //    "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/app"
            //    "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"
                "/var/www/html": "C:/Users/pnoskov/Documents/docker/projector/www"
            },
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Xdebug поставился:

```
PS C:\Users\pnoskov\Documents\docker\projector> docker-compose exec webserver bash
root@43e19f1ba48d:/var/www/html# php -m
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype        
curl
date
dom
fileinfo     
filter       
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
imagick
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

[image: Вывод phpinfo()]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что проблема в указании удаленного хоста xdebug:
xdebug.remote_host = <IP_ADDR>

<IP_ADDR> можно получить :
$ hostname -I | cut -d ' ' -f1

Comment: если это ответ на вопрос, то постарайтесь, пожалуйста, сформулировать его более чётко. для этого нажмите [edit].